# How to run telerik RadWindow from code behind

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radwindow

I am trying to run telerik rad window from code behind. But I have some issues.
I don't know is it important but I am trying to run rad window from button clicked in edit mode from rad grid.

```
RadWindow window1 = new RadWindow();
window1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";
window1.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
window1.ID = "RadWindow1";
window1.Width = 500;
window1.Height = 300;
window1.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;    
rwm_WindowManager.Windows.Add(window1);
```

On the page I also have `RadAjaxManager` and `rwm_WindowManager` I put in `RadAjaxPanel`.
Problem is that this rad window never shows up. There are no errors but no rad window also.

Comment: can you show the code with the RadAjaxPanel and the WindowManager? Maybe the Panel is not visible at all. Are you sure that the shown code is called when clicking the button?

Comment: please, could you try to change RadAjaxPanel to ordinary asp:Panel and check if the RadWindow shows up?

Answer (score 3):

```
 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
            OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Open window" CommandName="OpenWindow" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

........................

```
 protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
            new { ID = "1", Name ="Name11",ParentID = "0"},
            new { ID = "2", Name ="Name11",ParentID = "0"},
            new { ID = "3", Name ="Name11",ParentID = "0"},
            new { ID = "4", Name ="Name11",ParentID = "0"}
        };
    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "OpenWindow")
    {
        //RadWindowManager
        RadWindow window1 = new RadWindow();
        window1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        window1.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
        window1.ID = "RadWindow1";
        window1.Width = 500;
        window1.Height = 300;
        RadWindowManager1.Windows.Add(window1);

    }
}
```

put your RadWindowManager inside RadAjaxPanel.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. My problem was that I omitted RadAjaxManager (there was only RadAjaxPanel). Consider an user control with RadAjaxPanel which I want open a RadWindow from and this control is used on many pages. Each page can contain many such controls but one page can contain only one RadWindowManager. Is it possible to achieve such scenario?

Comment: If the RadWindowManager is omitted and the RadWindow is directly added into RadAjaxPanel, everything works fine. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue. I resolved it like so:

```
RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ResponseScripts.Add(String.Format("$find('{0}').show();", window1.ClientID));
```

My applications use RadAjax which makes the `VisibleOnPageLoad` property problematic, so I avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [How to refresh parent page grid when close radwindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054907/how-to-refresh-parent-page-grid-when-close-radwindow/18082262#18082262) and examine the links from my answer. The approach is much cleaner and will spare you a couple of unnecessary postbacks.